# typescript intellisense incomplete

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a pretty fresh installation of vscode and a super simple project where a ts file imports type definitions from another file. I cannot seem to get the intellisense to work and all i can see is the import statement on hover. This is what it looks like

[image: intellisense unexpected]

Note: The behavior is the same if i don't use my "~" shortcut. so the behavior is the same if i do the following

```
import {FilterType, filterReducer} from '../../utils/filters';
```

I would give more information but i'm not sure what information would be required. Here's what i can think of

vscode version : 1.53
node version: 14.15.4
tsc version : 4.1.5
os : ubuntu 20.04

PS: I have this same issue on vim as well.

Comment: Are you sure the import path is correct? How exactly and what tool does expand the `~`?

Comment: Nice question. I have it set in tsconfig.json and babel as well. But, this behavior is also present when i do a usual `import { FilterType, filterReducer } from '../../utils/filters';`